# How to change page title using RoR based on :id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a website built in Ruby on Rails (backend) and React.js (frontend), so all the content is loaded dynamically and page changes are effected via AJAX. I would like to change the html page title to the Article Title if the user is browsing to an article. So, if a user visits website.com/discuss/14 , I want the page title to be updated to the Article Title where topic_id = 14. However, if the user visits website.com/#contactpage or any other page that is not a discussion page, then there should be a default title instead.

Right now, my code works only for _escaped_fragment_ for SEO but does not work for a normal user.

This is the code:

--- frontend.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <% if params["_escaped_fragment_"].present?  %>
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/escaped_title' %>
  <% elsif Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('discuss') %>
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/discuss_title' %>
  <% else %>
    <title>website.com:default title</title>
  <% end %> 
.....rest of my page code
```

So the first condition (escaped fragment) works perfectly fine. It's the second condition (routes -> discuss) that is failing. This is the code for each of the partials:

---- _escaped_title.html.erb

```
<% if params[:_escaped_fragment_] %>
  <% if params[:_escaped_fragment_].match(/\/discuss\/(\d+)/) %>
    <% topic = Topic.statistic.find_by_id($1) %>
    <% if topic %>
      <% opts = {sector: true, statistic: true, background: true} %>
      <% json = topic.show_data(opts) %>
     <% plain_question = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(topic.question) %>
      <title><%= plain_question %> - on website.com</title>

    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---- _discuss_title.html.erb

```
<% topic = Topic.find_by_id(params[:id]) %>
 <% if topic %>
    <% opts = {sector: true, statistic: true, background: true} %>
    <% json = topic.show_data(opts) %>
    <% plain_question = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(topic.question) %>
    <title><%= plain_question %> - on website.com</title>    
 <% end %>
```

I suspect that the first few lines of my _discuss_title.html.erb is incorrect, but I don't know how to do it correctly. How do I get the current topic id properly and pass it to a variable for it to search my database?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

First off simplify your view by creating a helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title
    content_tag(:title, @title || "Some default title")
  end
end
```

Which is used as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= title %>
</head>
```

We have now moved the complexity out of the view and we can control the page title via setting the view context instance variable `@title`.

The simplest way to implement this would be to actually set the title in the controllers which actually need a custom title:

```
class DiscussionController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_discussion, only: [:show, :edit, :delete, :update]
  before_filter :set_title, only: [:show], if: lambda{ |controller| controller.request.format.html? }

  private

  def set_discussion
    @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_title
     # since we get the value from the database record and 
     # not the params we don't need to worry about escaping.
     @title = "Discussing article #{ @discussion.id }"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much - perhaps a simpler question then: How do I extract the current ID from the page and use that to trigger the change instead? That is, what is the correct way for me to extract the "14" from website.com/discuss/14 ?
I don't want to make too many changes to the code (as per your suggestion) and I'm inheriting this code from someone else.

Comment: Well you could set the @title based on the request url in your applicationController. But its a suboptimal solution. Use version control and tests and get over your fear of "making to many changes" instead. You can make an omelette without cracking any eggs.

Comment: Thanks again. How would I "set the @title based on the request url in my application controller" exactly? Sorry - I'm still learning, so I have a long way to go. I just wanted to make a simple edit to a page my developer did, hence my desire not to do too much to his code.

Comment: I tried it your way and it didn't work either. No errors, but the page title only stayed at the "some default title" and never changed. I even tried to set @ title to a fixed string "testing title" and it would not change so it was not the database call that failed; it was the before_filter (I think)